# How can I change Parent object's position in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**Image:**
[image: Imagee]

I am trying to make it move entire Inventory object 
when dragging "NamePanel" object.
I added this script to "NamePanel" object
and it makes only NamePanel to move.

How should I edit my script to do that?
how can I get Parent's transform component?
since I'm not a English speaker, it's hard to get
information by only searching...

```
public class InventoryControl : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler
{
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public Vector3 offset;

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        offset = transform.position - (Vector3)eventData.position;
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = (Vector3)eventData.position + offset;
    }
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How should I edit my script to do that? how can I get Parent's transform component?

Use `transform.parent`

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    transform.parent.position = (Vector3)eventData.position + offset;
}
```